# Viruses for android on web pages help please

Tags: web, virus

I entered a web site from my LG G2 and i took a warning on screen in web browser. (not chrome, other official web browser called "internet") It says: "Warning. G2 has infected. Install an antivirus from Google Play" and there was OK button on warning and when i clicked OK it sent me to 360 Total Securty page on Google Play. And also on browser, another web pages opened. (ali.express was one of them) How can it know my phone is G2? is it possible a web page can know what is my phone model? was it a virus? has my phone infected? Please help thanks..

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not related to programming at all. You might be interested in our sister site, [android.se] which focuses on Android end-user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible for a website to get information about you, such as your phone type, operating system, browser, browsing history, etc (see [Mobile Device Detection)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_device_detection).

More than likely - I say this without knowledge of website visited - the website wants you to download their virus scanner without you actually having a virus.  This happens all the time on computers as well when you visit a site and get a pop-up that your computer has been infected and to install a specific program, which might ask you to call tech support and cost money.

[image]

My advice would be to download one of the top virus scanners in google play (not the one the website suggested) and do a scan.  This should alleviate any concerns.

Careful where you click.